# Rewriting 4^(n) as a^(n-1)

Tags: exponentiation

How can I rewrite $4^n$ as $a^{n-1}$? Where $a$ is known?

I thought about solving with logarithms but that seems long-winded for something so simple... I think I am just too tired right now, I cannot think.

$$
4^n=a^{n-1} \implies
n \log 4 = (n-1) \log a \\
\frac{n\log4}{n-1}=\log a\implies a=4^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$$

Is that correct? There must be a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write  $$4^n=a^{n-1}\implies 4\times 4^{n-1}=a^{n-1}\implies 4=\left(\frac a4 \right)^{n-1}\implies \frac a4=\sqrt[{n-1}]4\implies a= 4\times \sqrt[{n-1}]4$$

Comment: Does this mean $a^{n-1}=4^{n-1}\cdot 4$?

Comment: Of course.  The right hand is $4^{n-1+1}=4^n$ so this is just the relation you started with.